# Como deixar os selects obrigatórios e deixar a primeira opção como padrão?

Tags: php, wordpress

***deixei em negrito o local dos selects***

```html
<!-- Adiciona o cabeçalho (header.php) -->
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<section class="orcamento-cw module">
 <div class="container wrap">

  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 link-topo">
    <a href="<?php echo get_home_url() ?>">Página Inicial ></i></a> <?php the_title() ?>
    <hr>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">

    <?php
    $galeria = get_field('galeria');
    if($galeria){
     foreach ($galeria as $imagem) {
      $imageGaleria = $imagem['sizes']['large'];
      $imageThumbnail = $imagem['sizes']['thumbnail'];
      $title = $imagem['title'];

      $imgGrande .='
      <div class="swiper-slide text-center">
       <img src="'.$imageGaleria.'" alt="'.$attr.'">
      </div>';

      $miniatura .='
      <div class="swiper-slide">
       <img src="'.$imageThumbnail.'" alt="'.$attr.'">
      </div>';
     }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide text-center">
       <img src="<?php orcamento_cw_the_imgDestaque(get_the_ID(),'large') ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>">
      </div>
      <?php echo $imgGrande ?>
     </div>
     <!-- Add Arrows -->
     <div class="swiper-button-next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
     <div class="swiper-button-prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
       <img src="<?php orcamento_cw_the_imgDestaque(get_the_ID(),'thumbnail'); ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>">
      </div>
      <?php echo $miniatura ?>
     </div>
    </div>

   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1">
      <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
      <hr>
      <?php
       if(get_field('resumo')){
        the_field('resumo');
       }
       **if(get_field('atributos')){
        $selects = array();
        $i=0;
        $atributos = explode(PHP_EOL,get_field('atributos'));
        foreach($atributos as $atributo){
         $opcoes = explode(':',$atributo);
         $name = $opcoes[0];
         if(!empty($opcoes[1])){
          $opcoes = explode(';',$opcoes[1]);
         }
         $selects[$i] = array('name'=>$name,'options'=>$opcoes);        
         
         $i++;**
         
        }
       }
       ?>
       <form id="addproduto"  method="get">
       <div class="atributosdiv">
        <?php foreach ($selects as $option):?>
         <label for="<?php echo $option['name'];?>"><?php echo $option['name'];?></label>
         <select class="form-control" id="<?php echo $option['name'];?>" name="<?php echo $option['name'];?>">
          <option value=""></option>
          <?php foreach ($option['options'] as $option): ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $option;?>"><?php echo $option;?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
         </select>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
       </div>
       </form>
       <?php
       $config = get_option('configOrcamento');
       $orcamento_text = (orcamentoConfig('single_produto_texto')) ? orcamentoConfig('single_produto_texto') : 'Enviar Orçamento';
       $orcamento_back_color = orcamentoConfig('single_produto_cor_fundo');
       $orcamento_text_color = orcamentoConfig('single_produto_cor_texto');

       $car= (isset($_COOKIE["carrinho"])) ? $_COOKIE["carrinho"] : "";
       if(isset($_COOKIE["carrinho"]) && $car != ''){
        $array = unserialize(stripslashes($car));
       }
       $quantCar = ($array[$post->ID] != '') ? $array[$post->ID] : 1;
      ?>
      <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 15px; max-width: 150px">
       <span class="input-group-addon">Quant.</span>
       <input type="number" id="quant<?php echo $post->ID ?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $quantCar ?>">
      </div>
      <button style="background-color: <?php echo $orcamento_back_color ?>; color: <?php echo $orcamento_text_color ?>" class='btn btn-lg btn-block <?php echo orcamentoConfig('single_produto_class') ?> produto-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>' onclick="orcamento(<?php echo $post->ID ?>, 'page-produto');"><?php echo $orcamento_text ?></button>
      <br>
      <div class="compartilhe">
       <p>Compartilhe:</p>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a id="comp-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?>+<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Share on Twitter" onclick="window.open(this.href,'galeria','width=680,height=470'); return false;" title="Galeria de fotos" ><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a id="comp-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&title=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook" onclick="window.open(this.href,'galeria','width=680,height=470'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
         <a id="comp-google" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Share on Google Plus" onclick="window.open(this.href,'galeria','width=680,height=470'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 descricao-produto">
    <?php the_content() ?>
   </div>
   <?php
   if(get_field('relacionados')){
    ?>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <hr>
     <h3>Relacionados</h3>
     <div class="row">
      <?php
      $relacionados = get_field('relacionados');
      $orcamento_text = (orcamentoConfig('produtos_texto')) ? orcamentoConfig('produtos_texto') : 'Orçamento';
      $orcamento_back_color = orcamentoConfig('produtos_cor_fundo');
      $orcamento_text_color = orcamentoConfig('produtos_cor_texto');
      $orcamento_class = orcamentoConfig('produtos_class');
      foreach( $relacionados as $post){
       setup_postdata($post);
       $style = 'style="min-height: auto;"';

       ?>
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center">
         <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">
          <table style="min-height: 190px; width:100%;">
           <tr>
            <td class="text-center">
             <img src="<?php orcamento_cw_the_imgDestaque('medium')?>" alt="<?php the_title()?>">
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </a>
         <div class="titulo">
          <h4 style="min-height: 50px;"><?php the_title()?></h4>
         </div>
         <button onclick="orcamento('<?php echo $post->ID ?>', 'page-produto');" style="background-color: <?php echo $orcamento_back_color?>; color: <?php echo $orcamento_text_color ?>" class="<?php echo $orcamento_class ?> produto-<?php echo get_the_ID()?>">
          <?php echo $orcamento_text; ?>
         </button>
        </div>
       </div>
       <?php
      }

      wp_reset_postdata();
      ?>
     </div>
    </div>
    <?php
   }
   ?>
  </div>

 </div>
</section>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
?>


<!-- Adiciona o rodapé (footer.php) -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para ser um campo obrigatório é necessário usar o "required" e para deixar uma opção padrão, voce precisa colocar dentro da tag option "selected"

```
<select name="nome_do_campo" required>
<option value="" selected></option>
</select>
```